# jQuery multiselect dropdown check boxes getting populated after option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use jQuery multiselect plugin. Check boxes are getting populated after the option text. Is there any configuration to place them at left?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating "bootstrap-select.min.js" to V-1.13.3 and removing "bootstrap-select.min.css" resolved the issue. Didn't get time to analyze why that was happening. Will update the answer once find actual cause.